# Debugging Java with Eclipse: process is suspended, but it doesn't throw any exception

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, exception, block

Debugging one my applications in Java, there came a moment when the process and its threads became suspended, the logging (directed to file, no console) was interrupted, but the program didn't throw an exception, although there may be a cause in the Java program.
This happened in some cases, in another case the entire Eclipse got blocked.

The computer which the program is executed on has enough free RAM.

The same program, run using a more powerful computer, behaved normally.

What may be the cause?
Does Eclipse have some limitation causing this behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse can suspend program execution when it encounters **uncaught exceptions** or **compilation errors**. It is possible that you are not seeing the exception in your logs because the exception was not handled. By default that would print the exception to the console, which you can still access if your logger captures and files it somewhere or you have access to the console.

Another reason to suspend execution is access modification of a watch point.

You can find and edit these debug settings under **Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Debug**

RAM has nothing to do with breakpoints and their behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse is starting as java program so, try to increase memory available for eclipse (in eclipse.ini)
Details can be found here: [http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse%3F](http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_increase_the_heap_size_available_to_Eclipse?)

I am using -Xmx768m

Comment: If i run Eclipse from command line no error about memory is displayed. With -Xmx768m it happens the same, i will try to increase -Xmx value.